# uninitialized constant RailsAdmin error after reinstalling rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am upgrading an app from Rails 3.2.6 to 4.1.1

During the upgrade, I uncommented the RailsAdmin gem and proceeded with fixing all the dependencies with all other gems that I had.

I recently re-integrated RailsAdmin by bundling the latest RailsAdmin gem:

```
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 0.6.2'
```

I also rail the following command:

```
rails g rails_admin:install
```

I am now getting the following error upon starting my server:

" **uninitialized constant RailsAdmin** "

I do indeed have Devise running on my application, but in my routes I have disabled Devise admin access in my routes. I have tried reinstalling RailsAdmin gem but that does not seem to work.

Here is my `routes.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :craigslist_shares

  devise_for :users,token_authentication_key: "auth_token", controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :users, only: [:index,:show] do
    collection do
      get :current
    end
  end

  resources :events do
    collection do
      post :facebook
      get :feed
      get :search
    end
    resources :attendees
    member do
     match "transaction", :as => :transit_to, via: [:get, :post]
     match "pitch", :as => :hitch_ride_to, via: [:get, :post]
     match "offer", :as => :offer_ride_to, via: [:get, :post]
    end
  end

....
....
```

Here is the `rails_admin.rb`:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ### Popular gems integration

  # == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  ## == Cancan ==
  # config.authorize_with :cancan

  ## == PaperTrail ==
  # config.audit_with :paper_trail, 'User', 'PaperTrail::Version' # PaperTrail >= 3.0.0

  ### More at https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end
end
```

Comment: do you have `class RailsAdmin end` defined somewhere? I think that's what the error message is about